# Does setting up VLAN on the ports on my switch makes the packet coming out of those ports tagged?

Tags: vlan

I got so confused studying VLANS.

[image]

[image]

Whenever I try to setup my laptop with VLANID 200,i cant access the MMC (managed media converter) web gui or management.

I have setup the VLANID 200 (on my laptop) with the right IP subnet range to that of the mmc.

The set IP interface in the MMC are these ones:

VLAN 1 - 10.1.1.1 /24

VLAN 4005 - 10.211.1.1 -16 (for management)

Whenever I setup VLAN 4005 on my laptop I can ping the mmc.But when I set up VLAN 200 on my laptop I can't.

Based on the above diagram, do I have to setup an IP address (on the mmc) for VLAN 200 and VLAN 300 each? I thought I was only supposed to setup an IP address (on the mmc device) for the management VLAN which is the 4005.

BTW: the port from mmc to laptop is port 3 and from mmc to cisco switch is port 1 as shown in the image above.

Thanks for any help guys.. I'm trying to learn VLAN and have read other posts in here..

Comment: If the management IP is not on the same subnet as the management station IP (your PC), then there will need to be routing in the network.  If there is no routing, then you will need the two IPs to be on the same subnet.  Nobody can tell you whether or not adding VLAN 200 or 300 IPs to your MMC will help, since you have not told us specifically what that device is.  It may help get traffic to the MMC, but for all we know it may be built in that management has to be on VLAN 4095 so we can't help without further information.  We also don't know whether you have any routing in your network.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are using special drivers, your laptop can't understand 802.1q framing.   Set your switch port 1 to access (VLAN 200), or, leave it as a trunk, but set the native VLAN to 200.